# Property of $Q$ such that $\frac{x^TQx}{\|x\|^2} = \text{const}, \ \ \ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

I am curious about the following problem:

1. suppose $Q^TQ = I$, i.e., $Q$ is orthogonal
2. we want $$\frac{x^TQx}{\|x\|^2} = \text{const}, \ \ \ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n$$

My question is what properties of $Q$ to let this equality hold?

I think the only property is $Q=I$. Are there any other properties?

Comment: $Q=Q^T$ i.e. Q symmetric seems sufficient, in addition to $Q$ orthogonal. $Q$ then corresponds to an orthogonal base change

Comment: @Damien I think even if no symmetric, it is an orthogonal base change

Comment: You are right of course. It was too late yesterday  when I posted it. But the symmetry condition seems sufficient. Do you agree ?